# "Permission denied" error when trying to switch branches

Tags: git, permissions, branch, file-permissions, git-reset

I am trying to use `git reset --hard` and I get this error:

`fatal: cannot create directory at '[path]/img/products': Permission denied`

I have not changed permissions and everything was working correctly before. Then I try `git checkout [branch name]` and I get this:

```
error: cannot stat '[path]/img/products': Permission denied
error: cannot stat '[path]/img/products': Permission denied
error: cannot stat '[path]/img/products': Permission denied
error: cannot stat '[path]/img/products': Permission denied
error: cannot stat '[path]/img/products': Permission denied
error: cannot stat '[path]/img/products': Permission denied
error: cannot stat '[path]/img/products': Permission denied
error: cannot stat '[path]/img/products': Permission denied
error: cannot stat '[path]/img/products': Permission denied
error: cannot stat '[path]/img/products': Permission denied
error: cannot stat '[path]/img/products': Permission denied
error: cannot stat '[path]/img/products': Permission denied
error: cannot stat '[path]/img/products': Permission denied
error: cannot stat '[path]/img/products': Permission denied
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
        [path]/img/products/icons.png
        [path]/img/products/buttons.png
Please commit your changes or stash them before you switch branches.
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
        [path]/img/leftbtn.png
        [path]/img/rightbtn.png
        [path]/img/logo.png
Please move or remove them before you switch branches.
Aborting
```

Everything was working correctly before and I suddenly started to experience the problems above. I simply want to switch branches. What do you recommend to try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weird. I tried again `git checkout [branch name]` and this time this is he error that I see:

```
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
        [path]/img/leftbtn.png
        [path]/img/rightbtn.png
        [path]/img/logo.png
Please move or remove them before you switch branches.
Aborting
```

I deleted those files, tried `git checkout [branch name]` again, and I could switch branches successfully this time.